# Partition a set of 2n integers into two subsets of n integers whose sum is positive

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a set of *2n* integers, is it possible to find a partition into two subsets of *n* integers, sum of each is positive.

My idea: We denote the values of the set *v[1], ..., v[2n]*.
Let *S[j, k, s1, s2] = 1* if there exists a partition of the first *j* integers of the set into two subsets of *k* and *j-k* integers respectively, such that the first subset sums up to *s1* and the second subset sums up to *s2*. (*s1* and *s2* can be negative of course)

We have the following relations : *S[j+1, k, s1, s2]=1* iff *S[j, k-1, s1-v[j+1], s2]=1* or *S[j, k, s1, s2-v[j+1]]*. The reason for that is that you must add the *j+1 th" element to either the "first" subset or the "second".

The answer to the problem is yes if there is *s1_0>0* and *s2_0>0* such that S[2n, n, s1_0, s2_0]=1.

What do you think? Is there a better way (in terms of time / space complexity)? I assumed from the start this was a dynamic-programming problem, would there be other approaches?

Comment: Any sequence that has negative sum can't be split into two sequences both of which have positive sums (of any lengths). If you restrict to sequences that have positive sum, the sequence [2, -1] can't be split into two subsequences of length 1 such that both has positive sum.

Comment: Well yea sure, what you mention are specific cases though.

Comment: The subsequences need to be contiguous, or they are partitions of size n?

Comment: Could you post a non-trivial example?

Comment: If they were contiguous we would have only one partition. Remember the lenghts of the sequences.

Comment: It is very, very unclear. Your notation is confusing, and you do not clarify with regard to comments. So: you have a set of 2n integers, sum of them is positive. And you want do get 2 subsets of n integers, sum of each is positive too. Is that the question ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the question...

Comment: What exactly is a "relative integer" and how does it differ from a regular integer?

Comment: It is just a regular integer, I will edit that (english mistake).

Comment: I rephrased the statement of the problem, hopefully now it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not dynamic programming, but still an idea.

```
let A and B be two empty sets

sort v
for i in [0, 2, ..., 2n)
    // note that v[i] <= v[i + 1]
    assign v[i] to the set with the largest sum
    assign v[i + 1] to the set with the smallest sum

return sum(A) >= 0 and sum(B) >= 0
```

The idea is to distribute the numbers as evenly as possible and to limit the damage caused by negative numbers, while keeping the sets to the same cardinality

- when both sets have negative sum the numbers are assigned such that their sum decreases as litle as possible
- when exactly one set has positive sum the largest number will be assigned to the set with the negative sum
- when both sets have positive sum any assignment is fine

Comment: I'd give going from large absolute values to smaller ones a try.